# What is the consequence of negative probability in discrete_distribution?

Tags: c++

What is the consequence if we pass a probability vector with non-negative value into discrete distribution,e.g.:

```
discrete_distribution d({1,-2,3});
```

I try to search the documentation about it but seems no one mentions about it! is it undefined behaviour? I test it by asking it to generate a random number, it seems never returns 1 (which is the second element), is it real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the standard:

> Unless specified otherwise, the distribution parameters are calculated as: pk = wk/S for k = 0, . . . , n−1 , in which the values wk, commonly known as the weights , shall be non-negative, non-NaN, and non-infinity.

Therefore undefined behaviour.